# how to minimize if-else statements while showing alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, alert

I am showing `alerts if 3 textboxes or any single text box is empty`. For example:
if `all are empty then alert will be" please fill up all"`
`else if 1st and 2nd text boxes are empty then alert will be  "please fill up 1st and 2nd text box"`
similarly `if 1st and 3rd text boxes are empty then alert will be  "please fill up 1st and 3rd text box"`
similarly `if 2nd and 3rd text boxes are empty then alert will be  "please fill up 2nd and 3rd text box"`
similarly `if only 1st text box is empty then alert will be  "please fill up 1st text box"`
similarly `if only 2nd text box is empty then alert will be  "please fill up 2nd text box"`
similarly `if only 3rd text box is empty then alert will be  "please fill up 3rd text box"`

But problem is i have to write so many `if-else statements` in javascript if `number of text boxes are 10 or more`. Is their any solution for this to minimize the `code` and `accordingly alert will come if any of the above condition satisfies`?

I have written the `if-else code` individually but it is very lengthy like this:

```
 <form name="frm" action="confirmsubmit.jsp">
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation() {
  var textboxname1=document.frm.textboxname1;
  var textboxname2=document.frm.textboxname2;
  var textboxname3=document.frm.textboxname3;

 //alert if all text boxes are empty

       if((textboxname1.value==null)||(textboxname1.value=="")&& (textboxname2.value=="")||(textboxname2.value==null)){
   alert("Please fill up first text box<br/>Please fill up second text box<br/>Please fill up 3rd text box");//alert for all
           textboxname1.focus();
           return false
       }

  //alert if 2nd text box is empty

         else if((textboxname2.value=="")||(textboxname2.value==null))
           {
 alert("Please Please fill up second text box");//alert for 2nd text box
           textboxname2.focus();
           return false 
           }              

   //alert if 3rd text box is empty   

         else if((textboxname3.value=="")||(textboxname3.value==null))
           {
 alert("Please Please fill up third text box");//alert for 3rd text box
           textboxname3.focus();
            return false 
           }  

          // similarly i have to show alert if 2nd and 3rd boxes are empty and so on, but is there any solution to minimize the code? 

            return true

   }
  //-->
  </script> 


<input type="text" name="textboxname1"/>
<input type="text" name="textboxname2"/>
<input type="text" name="textboxname3"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirmation()"/> 
 </form>
```

Comment: how about putting all values into array and checking this array in a cycle for '' or null

Comment: Alert dialogs are really user-unfriendly for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check every empty checkbox use this simple jquery selector:

```
jQuery('input.test').not('[value]').each(function() {
    var blankInput = jQuery(this);
    //do what you want with your input
});
```

your js will be like this:

```
function confirmation(domForm) {
    var jForm = jQuery(domForm);
    var values = jForm.find('.check').serializeArray();

    var failedFields = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var o = values[i];
        if(o.value == null || o.value.length == 0) {
            failedFields.push(o.name);
        }
    }

    if(failedFields.length > 0) {
        var message = ''; 
        if(failedFields.length == values.length) {
            message = 'fill all fields please';
        }
        else {
            message = 'please fill the fields:';
            for(var i = 0; i < failedFields.length; i++) {
                message += "\n";
                message += failedFields[i];
                }
        }

        alert(message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

call confirmation on your onsubmit! like this:

```
<form name="frm" onsubmit="return confirmation(this)" action="confirmsubmit.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="textboxname1" class="check"/>
    <input type="text" name="textboxname2" class="check"/>
    <input type="text" name="textboxname3"/>
    <input type="submit"/> 
 </form>
```

Comment: just one more doubt if i have two combo box then how should i edit your jquery? please help me

Comment: @tom i have changed my code and work with `serializeArray`... check out

Comment: just one doubt, if for a text box(text box4) i do n't want to do validation then how should i edit your jquery? please help me

Comment: ok i edited.... now it will check just fields with the class `check`... now you habe to set the class attribute to every validateable-element. dude you owe me a beer

Comment: thanks a lot silly , i have just one more doubt but i am thinking whether i should ask you or not, should i ask?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8392/discussion-between-silly-and-tom)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
emptyTextboxen = []

for each textboxen as textbox
    if textbox is empty
        emptyTextboxen.push(textbox)

if emptyTextboxen.length == textboxen.length
    message = 'Please fill up all textboxen'
else if emptyTextboxen.length > 0
    message = 'Please fill up textboxen '
    for each emptyTextboxen as emptyTextbox
        message += emptyTextbox + ', '
else
    message = 'Life is good'
```

Comment: ok but error is coming when i am writing the above code in javascript, can you please modify your code little bit please

Comment: Again, this is **pseudocode**. It's not real Javascript. It's supposed to demonstrate the logic needed to implement this without an exponential number of `if .. else`. **You** will have to write the *actual* script based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GhSVz/1/)

```
$('form[name="frm"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    var empty = $('input[type="text"]', this).filter(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=="") return this;
    });
    if (empty.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();            
        if (empty.length == $(this).children('[type="text"]').length) {
            alert('please fill up all');
        }else{
            var str = 'please fill up ';
            $(empty).each(function(index, value) {
                var Sepa = index==empty.length-2 ? ' and ' : ', ',
                    Numb = parseInt(this.name[this.name.length-1]);
                Sepa = index==empty.length-1 ? '' : Sepa;                        
                Numb=Numb==1?'1st':Numb==2?'2nd':Numb==3?'3rd':Numb+'th';
                str=str+Numb+Sepa;
            });
            str=str+' text box';
            alert(str);                
        }   
    }else{
        alert('All are filled, form will be submitted');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you will be able to do this. To do this with minimum code I suggest the following approach. Add a class to all the textboxes and if any of them is empty show the alert

```
<input type="text" name="textboxname1" class ="test"/>
<input type="text" name="textboxname2" class ="test"/>
<input type="text" name="textboxname3" class ="test"/>
```

and in the scripts

```
function confirmation() {
   var elements = $('.test');
   var index = 1;

   var message = "";
   elements.each(function(){
       if($(this).val() == ""){
        message += "textbox no" + index + "is empty ";          

       }

   index = index + 1;
   });
  if(message != ""){
   alert(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: int index? do you mean var index?

Comment: And if there are ten inputs, all of which are empty, I get ten separate dialogs popping up, each of which I have to dismiss by clicking a button?

Comment: @BobbyJack I added a return false, so I think for the first error it will give an alert

Comment: and i think you sould be use `val()` method instead the `val` property

Comment: Fair point, but that's still not great: fix first error, get another alert, fix that error, ... Etc.

Comment: ok almost ok, you have to devine your message outside of your each loop... after `var index=1;` define your message var `var message="";`... in the loop you have to remove the `var` statment :-) sorry